# Accessing factory defined in another module in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, module

Can we call the factory functions defined in one module from another module? If so, how?

Let's say my first module is defined in `moduleOne.js` file as:

```
var myModule = angular.module('MyServiceModuleOne', []);
myModule.factory('notify', function () {
    return {
        sampleFun: function () {
            // some code to call sampleFunTwo()
        },
    };
});
```

And my second module in `moduleTwo.js` as:

```
var myModuleTwo = angular.module('MyServiceModuleTwo', []);
myModuleTwo.factory('notifytwo', function () {
    return {
        sampleFunTwo: function () {
            // code
        },
    };
});
```

How to call `sampleFunTwo()` from `sampleFun()`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You need to *inject* `MyServiceModuleTwo` into `MyServiceModule`:

```
var myModuleTwo= angular.module('MyServiceModuleTwo',[]);
var myModule= angular.module('MyServiceModuleOne', ['MyServiceModuleTwo']);
```

Then *inject* `notifytwo` into `notify`:

```
myModule.factory('notify', function(notifytwo) {
    return {
        sampleFun: function() {
            notifytwo.sampleFunTwo();
        }      
    };
});


myModuleTwo.factory('notifytwo', function() {
    return {
        sampleFunTwo: function() {
            alert('From notify two');
        }    
    };
});
```

And the code on [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jcOwg8HgBGPtod4yCR5j)

Comment: What if both modules are already injected on the main module?