# How to call a function from another module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

In my angularJS application, I have two modules : module A and module B.

```
angular.module('A').controller('ACtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.alertA = function(){alert('a');}
    //...
});

angular.module('B').controller('BCtrl',function($scope){
    //...
});
```

How to call the function `alertA` in the module B ?

Comment: Your function should be refactored into a service. That's how functions are shared and cross-injected in Angular. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18607010/accessing-factory-defined-in-another-module-in-angularjs

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33882051/call-a-function-in-a-controller-in-another-module-in-angularjs

Comment: Nice, thanks for your answers.

Comment: Hello! Please accept my answer if it solves your problem. :) [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/170863)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to define a factory in **module A**:

```
var moduleA= angular.module('A',[]);
moduleA.factory('factoryA', function() {
    return {
        alertA: function() {
            alert('a');
        }    
    };
});
```

Then use the `alertA` factory in **module B**:

```
angular.module('B',['A']).controller('BCtrl',function($scope,'factoryA'){
    factoryA.alertA();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Refactor your code in following these steps:

1. Define a service in module A
2. Add module A as dependency to module B
3. Inject the service into the controller

Here is an example:

```
angular.module('A').service('API', function ($http) {
    this.getData = function () { return $http.get('/data'); };
});

angular.module('B', ['A']).controller('dashboardCtrl', function ($scope, API) {
    API.getData().then(function (data) { $scope.data = data; });
});
```