# angularJS - my service not called getting error

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

my app config :

```
(function( ){
    "use strict";

    angular.module("blog", ["ngRoute",  "blog.controllers", "blog.services"  ]);

    function config ($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

        $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'modules/users/views/users-list.tpl.html',
            controller: 'User.controller',
            controllerAs: 'userlist'
        });
    }

    angular
    .module('blog')
    .config(config);

})( );
```

my service :

```
(function( ){

    "use strict";
    angular.module("blog.services", ["ngResource"])
    .service("userService", function( ) {

        console.log("service called");

        this.name = function( ) {
            // return $resource(BaseUrl + ‘/posts/:postId’, { postId: ‘@_id’ });
            return "Tech Mahindra";
        }

    })


})( );
```

my controller :

```
(function( ){
    "use strict";

    angular.module("blog.controllers", [ "userService" ])
    .controller("User.controller", function(  service ) {

        var userlist = this;
        userlist.name = "Nissan New Japan!!";
        console.log( "user controller ready!!");

        console.log("from service post : " , service.name( ) ); //throws error


        return userlist;
    });
})( );
```

What is wrong here? any one help me?

error i am getting:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module blog due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module blog.controllers due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module userService due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'userService' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

[error link](http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$injector/nomod?p0=userService)

Comment: can you post the error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should inject `blog.services` module into `blog.controllers` app instead of `userService`

```
angular.module("blog.controllers", [ "blog.services" ])
.controller("User.controller", function(userService ) {
```

Comment: then how to call the name method?

Comment: I am getting error like : `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: serviceProvider <- service <- User.controller`

Comment: Try injecting the name `userService` in your controller instead of `service` as you have now.

Comment: Are all these components in same file, if not are you sure you have included the script file containing the service code in your html

Comment: all are separate files. all are included

Comment: You should also inject `userService` into controller.

Comment: @Hadi - yes, it works. But why should we inject `userService` again. any one explain me please? ( exactly we are using the same name here !)

Comment: It is clear. your service define in separate module so for using it you should inject it in app. and for using of all it's service also inject them. see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36704347/how-to-call-a-function-from-another-module